# JPA / OpenJPA ADD CONSTRAINT

Tags: jpa, constraints, openjpa

I am new in JPA and have a question how to tell JPA to ADD a CONSTRAINT to a  TABLE in DB2. I have the following Entity:

```
    @Entity
    public class Test {
        @Id
        private long id;
        private String a;
        private String b;
        ...
```

JPA generates the following DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE
    TEST
    (
        ID BIGINT NOT NULL,
        A VARCHAR(254),
        B VARCHAR(254),
        PRIMARY KEY (ID)
    );
```

So far, so good. But now I want to add a constraint to this DB2-Table which checks that one and only one of both columns A and B is NOT NULL. Something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE TEST ADD CONSTRAINT 
CONST CHECK(
        (A IS NOT NULL AND B IS NULL) OR  
        (A IS NULL AND B IS NOT NULL)
);
```

My question: Can JPA create this CONSTRAINT in DDL? If Yes: How can i tell JPA to create this CONSTRAINT? Via Annotations?

I use OpenJPA 2.4.2.